# What is the word 喉首目?

Tags: words, verbs

> イルーシュはがら空きになった**喉首目がけて**、今度は刃先を突き立てた。

The word 喉首目 is not in dictionaries,  but it's used in this context simply for throat (喉). What is this word?

Also, can someone confirm if けて is for 蹴る (kick), because Google translate it to "aim" I think that would make more sense in the context. 蹴る is the only verb I was able to find.

Comment: Presumably google translate is getting "aim" from the verb 目がける.

Comment: @Leebo oooh that's right, still 喉首 doesn't seem to exist, like throat-neck?

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%96%89%E9%A0%B8/

Comment: @Simon It's simplified version of "喉頸", because 頸 is not used in daily life - Link: [喉頸](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%96%89%E9%A0%B8-597103)".

Comment: を has been omitted after 喉首. It's 喉首を目がけて in standard formal Japanese, but the sentence may sound a little more dramatic without を.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment by Leebo. (I'm too newbie to put acomment)
'喉首目がけて' means '(イルーシュ) aim for the throat'.

喉首 may not be in some dictionary but used as obj when someone attacks or hits the throat-neck. Because it sounds more lurid than just '首' or '喉'.

For example, there is a card in M:tG '喉首狙い' originally 'Go for the Throat'.